# How to disable a jQuery function after screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable this navigation code after the screen is less than 1000px

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('body');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() > 50;
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $("#nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,1)');
          $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '4px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
       } else {
          $('#nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,0)');
          $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)');
       }
   });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you use $( window ).width(); in your function to selectively run the code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code with slight modification I would do this as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('body');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  var doScrollStuff;

  $(window).resize(function(){
    doScrollStuff = $(window).width() >= 1000;
  }).resize();

  if (startchange.length){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      if (doScrollStuff) {
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() > 50;

        if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $("#nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,1)');
          $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '4px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
        } else {
           $('#nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,0)');
           $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`on`<sup>jQuery API</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the event and use a specific name to easily unbind it later.

```
$(document).on("scroll.Nav", function () {
```

And then later, if some condition is met either in the callback of that `function(){` code segment, or in another code segment, simply use

```
$(document).off("scroll.Nav");
```

Comment: A bit confused. I'm a noob at jQuery. What do you mean by bind the events?

Comment: In this situation, that would mean attach them to the element. Binding can have broader use as well, for example in the scenario where you wish to have an event handle an element which was not yet present on the page. You should read the jQuery documentation for `on` that I linked the in the answer for a much more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var windowWidth = $(window);
windowWidth.on('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 1000){
        //do something
    }
})
```

In the //do something section, you can write your disable function in there. This code above will execute the inner function whenever the screen resizes and is less than 1000px.